# Error: "lateinit property adapter has not been initialized" cuando abro mi activity con un RecyclerView

Tags: android-studio, firebase, kotlin, recyclerview

Estoy desarrollando una app con Kotlin en Android Studio, pero tengo un problema cuando abro el PedirActivity donde tengo un RecyclerView me salta un error y se me cierra la app. El RecyclerView obtiene informacion desde Firebase Firestore, en la app ya tengo otro RecyclerView funcional donde copie partes de ese codigo para este RecyclerView, capaz copie algo mal y no se que.

el Logcat de mi error es este

```
2021-06-10 12:37:26.535 28824-28824/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ezdev.chepesdelivery, PID: 28824
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ezdev.chepesdelivery/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery.PedirActivity}: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property adapter has not been initialized
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property adapter has not been initialized
        at com.ezdev.chepesdelivery.PedirActivity.onCreate(PedirActivity.kt:35)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Acá paso mi código PedirActivity.kt .

```
package com.ezdev.chepesdelivery

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.ezdev.chepesdelivery.ui.RecyMenu.MyAdapterMenu
import com.ezdev.chepesdelivery.ui.RecyMenu.MyViewModelMenu
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_pedir.*


class PedirActivity : AppCompatActivity(), MyAdapterMenu.OnTiendaListener {

    private lateinit var adapter: MyAdapterMenu
    private val viewModel by lazy { ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModelMenu::class.java)}


    private val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pedir)

        var nombreTienda = intent.getStringExtra("nombreTienda")
        var tiendaEmail = intent.getStringExtra("emailTienda")


        title = "Menu de $nombreTienda"

        recyclerViewMenu.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerViewMenu.adapter = adapter
        observeData()

    }

    fun observeData(){
        viewModel.fetchTiendaData().observe(this, Observer {

            adapter.setListData(it)
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

        })
    }

    override fun onItemClick(nombre: String) {



    }

}
```

Creo que el Error se produce en el PedirActivity.kt pero si hace falta puedo pasar los demas códigos (Repo, Adapter, ViewModel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es que estás intentando usar la variable `adapter` sin antes haberle asignado un valor. Todo lo que debes hacer es crear el adapter y asignarlo a esa propiedad.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
    adapter = MyAdapterMenu()
    recyclerViewMenu.adapter = adapter
    observeData()
}
```